# $wpdb->replace Can't replace value of table wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I write code to save data in to the database table.

I want Replace a row in a table if it exists or insert a new row in a table if the row did not already exist.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

I use `$wpdb->replace` function and then add $`wpdb->insert_id` to end of code.

But when run my own wordpress plugin . only add new rows with values .Can't replace values.

```
 $wpdb->replace( $wpdb->prefix . 'fafa', 
   array( 
   'title' =>  trim($row->item(0)->nodeValue) ,
   'liveprice' =>  trim($row->item(2)->nodeValue)  ,
   'changing' =>   trim($row->item(4)->nodeValue)  ,
   'lowest' =>   trim($row->item(6)->nodeValue)  ,
   'topest' =>   trim($row->item(8)->nodeValue)  ,
   'time' =>   trim($row->item(10)->nodeValue)   ), 
   array( 
   '%s',
   '%s',
   '%s',
   '%s',
   '%s',
   '%s'
) );
 $wpdb->inser_Id;
```

table photo

[image: table]

[image: strucher]

In Following photo Now id is Unique

[image: db]

Comment: which of those fields are unique in that table: `'title'
   'liveprice',  'changing', 'lowest','topest','time'` ?

Comment: 'title' is uniqe @Alex

Comment: really? could you prove that by showing table structure?

Comment: Sorry . primary key is id ... I added photos  @Alex

Comment: primary key != unique

Comment: Oh, I I did not know primary key isn't unique.. I want replace all fields id-title-liveprice ,... @Alex

Comment: Now id is Unique .. I changed in table... you can see in top photo  @Alex

Comment: that what I guessed from the beginning. and that means that until your query doesn't include the same ID - it just creates new one. you never tried to update any unique record with any ID

Comment: OH.. Sorry.. unique now is title ..

Comment: really? do you know the structure of your table??? just include `CREATE TABLE` statement in your post, but not screenshots

Comment: Now I'm confused.. How can help me?

Comment: I want Replace a row in a table if it exists or insert a new row in a table if the row did not already exist... Two weeks is that I'm trying out .. But I'm stuck in this issue

Comment: if you know the record you want to update - you should send an ID of that row. if you don't know and you mean that the Title is enough to say that the record is the same - so set `title` as unique key in your table.

Comment: How can I Send Id of the row? can you write example code?@Alex

Answer (score 0):

this is in your code--->>>>>>>

$wpdb->inser_Id;  ***********************

it should be--->>>>>>>>

$wpdb->insert_Id;

Comment: No it shouldn't, it should be `$wpdb->insert_id;`